# repeat list in to a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a list let's say

```
k<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

I want to create a dataframe with let's say 5 rows using the same list in each row as shown below.

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  2  3  4
2  1  2  3  4
3  1  2  3  4
4  1  2  3  4
5  1  2  3  4
```

I tried doing:-

```
> rep(k, each = 5)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

However I am not able to get intended result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data.frame(t(replicate(5, k)))
#OR
data.frame(matrix(rep(k, each = 5), 5))
#OR
data.frame(t(sapply(1:5, function(x) k)))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  1  2  3  4
#2  1  2  3  4
#3  1  2  3  4
#4  1  2  3  4
#5  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: `data.frame(t(matrix(k,length(k),5))`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option  by converting the `vector` to `list` with `as.list`, change it to data.frame (`as.data.frame` and `rep`licate the rows

```
as.data.frame(as.list(k))[rep(1, 5),]
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
#1    1  2  3  4
#1.1  1  2  3  4
#1.2  1  2  3  4
#1.3  1  2  3  4
#1.4  1  2  3  4
```

---

Or another option is to take the transpose of the vector to get a row matrix, `rep`licate the rows and convert to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(t(k)[rep(1, 5),])
```

---

In `tidyverse`, one option is to convert to `tibble` and then `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
as.list(k) %>% 
    set_names(str_c("X",  seq_along(k))) %>% 
    as_tibble %>% 
    uncount(5)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#     X1    X2    X3    X4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3     4
#2     1     2     3     4
#3     1     2     3     4
#4     1     2     3     4
#5     1     2     3     4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
purrr::map_dfc(k, rep, 5)

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#      V1    V2    V3    V4
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     2     3     4
# 2     1     2     3     4
# 3     1     2     3     4
# 4     1     2     3     4
# 5     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: This should be the compact option

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table:

```
k = c(1,2,3,4)

n = 5 # Number of rows

df = data.table()
df = df[, lapply(1:length(k), function(x) rep(k[x], n))]

> df
   V1 V2 V3 V4
1:  1  2  3  4
2:  1  2  3  4
3:  1  2  3  4
4:  1  2  3  4
5:  1  2  3  4
```